# Given two lines g,h and a direction vector C, find the nearest positions to origin where a line with direction vector C can intersect both g and h

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I am trying to find the nearest position where the common normal C of the lines g and h (obtained using cross product with their direction vectors) intersect g and h (I need to find the nearest position where it intersects g and the nearest position where it intersects h)

g: (0,0,0) + λ(-0.171,0.970,-0,174)

h: (0,0,20) + λ(0,1,0)

direction vector C : (0.174,0,-0.171)

I am lost in figuring out the right approach to solving this and I haven't been able to track down similar examples.

Comment: It’s not clear what you are asking. Are you trying to find the points on each line corresponding to the shortest distance between the two lines? Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: If $g$ and $h$ are not parallel and are not intersecting then there is only one line which intersects $g$ and $h$ and is orthogonal to both of them. Then required point is on this line. Part I. Find point $X$ on $g$ such that line from $X$ having direction vector $C$ intersects $h$. Part II. Find point on line from $X$ having direction vector $C$ which is nearest to the origin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the lines $g$ and $h$ be given by

$g:  \  P(\lambda_1) = P_0 + \lambda_1 V $

$h:  \  Q(\lambda_2) = Q_0 + \lambda_2 W $

where $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 \in \mathbb{R} $ and for simplicity it is assumed that $V$ and $W$ are unit vectors.

Compute the vector $\vec{PQ} $

$\vec{PQ} = Q_0 - P_0 + \lambda_2 W - \lambda_1 V $

The squared distance function is given by

$ f(\lambda_1 , \lambda_2) = \| \vec{PQ} \|^2 \\
(Q_0  - P_0 + \lambda_2 W - \lambda_1 V ) \cdot (Q_0 - P_0 + \lambda_2 W - \lambda_1 V)\\
= (Q_0 - P_0) \cdot (Q_0 - P_0) + \lambda_2^2  + \lambda_1^2 + 2 \lambda_2 \ W \cdot (Q_0 - P_0) - 2 \lambda_1 \ V \cdot (Q_0 - P_0) - 2 \lambda_1 \lambda_2 \ V \cdot W$

At the minimum, we have the partial derivatives of $f$ with respect to $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ equal to zero.

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \lambda_1} = 2 \lambda_1 - 2 \ V \cdot (Q_0 - P_0) - 2 \lambda_2 \ V \cdot W = 0$

$\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial \lambda_2} = 2 \lambda_2 + 2 \ W \cdot (Q_0 - P_0) - 2 \lambda_1 \ V \cdot W = 0$

Dividing both equations through by $2$, we now have the following $2 \times 2 $ linear system

$ \begin{bmatrix} 1 && - \ V \cdot W \\ - \ V \cdot W && 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1 \\ \lambda_2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}  \ V \cdot (Q_0 - P_0) \\ -  \ W \cdot (Q_0 - P_0) \end{bmatrix}$

The can be solved quite easily for $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$.  Using Cramer's rule for solving linear systems, we get

$ \lambda_1 = \dfrac{ V \cdot(Q_0 - P_0) - (V \cdot W) W \cdot (Q_0 - P_0) }{ 1 - (V \cdot W)^2 } $

and

$ \lambda_2 = \dfrac{ - W \cdot (Q_0 - P_0) + (V \cdot W) V \cdot (Q_0 - P_0 ) }{ 1 - (V \cdot W)^2} $

And these simplify to

$ \lambda_1 = \dfrac{ ( V - (V \cdot W) W ) \cdot (Q_0 - P_0) }{ 1 - (V \cdot W)^2 } $

and

$ \lambda_2 = \dfrac{ (- W + (V \cdot W) V ) \cdot (Q_0 - P_0) }{ 1 - (V \cdot W)^2} $

Now that we have the minimizing $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$ we can compute the points $P$ and $Q$ on the lines $g$ and $h$ that the minimum distance between them from the top two equations.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer! Is vector PQ in this instance perpendicular to both g and h? 
I am also a little confused about solving the last equations for λ1 and λ2 , V,W Q0 and P0 are all vectors i.e. (x,y,z) how does the result become a real number? is it the length of the resulting vector from the formula?

Comment: Ah nevermind that second part, I was using normal multiplication instead of dot product

Comment: Yes,  vector $PQ $ with the values of $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$ that are the solution of the linear system, will be perpendicular to both $g$ and $h$